# Kusto query language - How to get exactly logs from previous day 7

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql

Kusto query language - How to get exact logs from 7 days ago

Example: Today is 03/17, I need a query that gets me logs only from 03/10.

I'm trying to use

pageViews
| where timestamp > ago(7d)

but it returns logs between 10/03 and 17/03

I need exactly the logs of the day.

Answer (score 4):

you could try using the `startofday()` function and the `between()` function.

for example:

```
PageViews
| where timestamp between(startofday(ago(7d)) .. 1d)
```